# Click on button with PHP or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to run a PHP script on my computer and renew my IP every half hour. I can do this by surfing to `http://192.168.1.1/` and clicking the disconnect button. (This is probably different for you, it depends on your router I guess)

Now I was thinking to load the website `http://192.168.1.1/` into an iFrame and then PHP or javascript could click the button.

I'm curious if these kind of things are possible with PHP or javascript? I saw in the source code that there is a javascript function behind the button. Can I run the function without physically clicking on the button?

I think an important note, I am not able to edit the source code of `http://192.168.1.1/`.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: schedule and ip renew command?

Comment: I think it would be more prudent to do what @GeoPhoenix recommended. Schedule it through Windows as opposed to trying to manipulate it via PHP or JS.

Comment: Yeah I know but that half hour was more like an example. It should actually renew when a certain task is completed and I'm not sure if I can pair this with time.

Comment: if its a task that fetches something from web, you might want to check out cURL and exec

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP and curl lib http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php to do that because we need to provide username and password for modem.

First, send request by curl with username and password.
Then, make the request as same as what the disconnect button do (or we could also provide username and password here).

Try this, may be it work for you!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $disconnectButtonActionURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```